# Equivalent condition of convergence of Filter

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, filters

Let $\mathcal F$ be a filter in a topological space $X$.

Denote $E_\mathcal F$ the set of elementary filters that are refined by $\mathcal F$. Elementary filters are the filters associated to sequences.

Clearly, if some filter $\mathcal E \in E_\mathcal{F}$ converges to a point $x$, then $\mathcal F$ must also converge to $x$, as $\mathcal F$ refines $\mathcal E$.

Is the converse also true? If $\mathcal F$ converges to $x$ does there exist an elementary filter $\mathcal E$ which is refined by $\mathcal F$ and converges to $x$?

I'm thinking it is false if $X$ is not first-countable (or sequential), is an example easy to construct? And in the case where $X$ is first-countable is it true?

Comment: Spaces that have this property are called _bisequential_. As far as I know bisequentiality implies sequentiality, but not the other way around. Therefore sequentiality is not enough. You might want to take a look at Michael's [_Quintuple quotient quest_](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X72900402), it has some examples and counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X=\omega_1 + 1 = [0,\omega_1]$, the space of all ordinals less than or equal to the least uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$, with the order topology. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the neighborhood filter of $\omega_1$. Of course $\mathcal{F}$ converges to $\omega_1$. However, *no* filter derived from a sequence refines $\mathcal{F}$.

If $X$ is first countable then the statement is true: Suppose $F$ is a filter converging to $x\in X$. Let $(U_n)$ be a countable neighborhood basis for $x$. Then for every $A\in F$ there is $n$ such that $U_n\subseteq A$. Let $V_n = \bigcap_{i\le n} U_i$. For each $n$ choose $s_n\in V_n$; thus $m\ge n$ implies $s_m\in V_n$. Then the sequence $s = (s_n)$ converges to $x$, and the filter $F_s$ of final segments of $s$ refines $F$: for every $A\in F$ there is $n$ such that for all $m\ge n$, $s_m\in A$.

The converse is not, in general: If $F_s$ is the elementary filter induced by a sequence, then $F_s$ contains countable sets (as well as uncountable sets), so in $\Bbb R$, as you note in your comment, no neighborhood filter can refine it, because all members of a neighborhood filter are uncountable, hence none can be contained in any of the countable members of $F_s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am really interested in the first countable case, do you think it is true for such spaces?

Comment: Your final question is a good one. I think it's true, but it bears some further thought, as I don't know the answer right off the top. I'll consider it more.

Comment: It turns out to be false almost always, consider the neighbourhood filter of a point in $\mathbb R$. If a filter is refined by the neighbourhood filter and refines the neighbourhood filter (ie converges), then it must be the neighbourhood filter. However every set in a neighbourhood filter in $\mathbb R$ has uncountable cardinality, whereas there are sets of countable cardinality in every elementary filter. So there is no convergent elementary filter that is refined by the neighbourhood filter.

Comment: It might be better to consider for $E_\mathcal F$ instead the set of elementary filters that either refine $\mathcal F$ or are refined by $\mathcal F$. Then we lose though the implication "a filter in $E_\mathcal F$ converges $\implies \mathcal F$ converges".

Comment: But an elementary filter *can* refine the neighborhood filter of a point — otherwise, no sequence in $\Bbb R$ could converge to anything.) All that's required is that every neighborhood *contain* some final segment of the sequence. I added a paragraph about why the converse is true for 1st countable spaces. Hopefully I didn't go off the rails somewhere ;/

Comment: you have turned around the construction I think. I was looking for elementary filters that are **refined by** the filter we started with (not refines that filter). My argument shows I think that in $\mathbb R$ no elementary filter is refined by a neighbourhood filter.

Comment: Ah: then, right: as you noted, by a simple cardinality argument, just as in the case $\omega_1 +1 $, that can't be. And (oops) I turned it around. I emended the answer.